# C# Linq query to find strings in an array that end with strings in another array

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of strings in a C# program.  One is a list of valid strings, the other is a list of directories:

```
string[] allDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
string[] validEndings = new string[] { "ABC", "DEF" };  // for example
```

How can I write a Linq statement to get just the string values in `allDirs` that end with any one of the values in `validEndings`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
allDirs.Where(d => validEndings.Any(d.EndsWith));
```